# Converting string to number in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using the below code
`int.Parse("376")` the result is coming as

int.Parse("376") =   0x00000178    int

and i tried to do as

`Convert.Toint32("376")` also then the result is same

please help me how to convert string to number?

Comment: 0x00000178 is the hexadecimal representation of 376. You have display as hexadecimal checked in your debugger.

Comment: Thank you Naveen. where to uncheck can you please help me on this

Comment: @Arya:- I have added the image for it. Please check!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working fine. `0x00000178` is the hexadecimal representation of `376`.

Your Hex button is enabled in Visual Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`0x00000178` is the [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) representation for `376`, so using `int.Parse` or `Convert.ToInt32` is OK.

However, I suggest to use the [`int.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) method:

```
int i;
if (int.TryParse(yourString, out i))
{
    // the string is converted successfully to an int, now you can find the int value in the variable 'i'
}
else
{
   // Can't convert to an int: the string contains probably some characters that aren't digits
}
```

Comment: +1 I think you have a typo 0x00000178 is the hexadecimal representation for 378. It should be 376.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine.  0x178 is hex based for 376 in decimal.